# Who to get difference between two id's as a same structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2014

I have a table like this:

```
id_begain | id_end | name | address | m_number
----------+--------+------+---------+-----------
1         | 5      | a    | hyd     | 099
7         | 9      | b    | pne     | 999
200       | 288    | c    | bng     | 1999
```

I need an output like this:

```
id  name  address  m_number
----------------------------
1    a      hyd     099
2    a      hyd     099
3    a      hyd     099
4    a      hyd     099
5    a      hyd     099 
7    b      pne     999
8    b      pne     999
9    b      pne     999
200  c      bng     1999
201  c      bng     1999
... 
288  c      bng     1999
```

Comment: NB: I suppose `id_begain` should be `id_begin`?

Comment: Mysql? Tsql? Sql server? Pick one! Mysql and SQL Server do not share a common sql dialect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive common table expression (`tbl` is your table):

```
with cte as (
    select id_begin, id_end, name, address, m_number 
    from   tbl
    union all
    select id_begin+1, id_end, name, address, m_number
    from   cte
    where  id_begin < id_end
)
select   id_begin as id, name, address, m_number
from     cte
order by 1;
```

Comment: I GOT MAXRECURSION ERROR ,I TRIED TO SET (OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0).BUT NOT SLOVED.......THANK YOU @PETER

Comment: This solution is indeed not suited for when you expect so many records. (no need to shout)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be handled using a calendar table approach, with a CTE containing the sequence of all numbers which might appear in your start or end columns:

```
WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n AS id
    FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
         (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
         (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n),
         (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thousands(n)
    WHERE ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
)

SELECT
    t1.id,
    t2.name,
    t2.address,
    t2.m_number
FROM numbers t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.id BETWEEN t2.id_begain AND t2.id_end
ORDER BY
    t1.id;
```

Comment: but  my number is more then 10000, my id like - 25645845651,tried to add (10000*tenthousands.n) how can I add more then that     ,Thanks @tim

Comment: Then extend the CTE to cover a higher sequence.